# In diffraction from a metal ruler, why can more orders be seen above the central bright spot than below?

Tags: diffraction

[image]

Looking at the attached image, why are there not as many orders under the 0th compared to above?

Comment: Have you tried a steeper angle, like straight down on the ruler?  In your drawing, it doesn't look like there is room for higher orders to squeeze in between the ruler and the 0 order.

Comment: So does there have to be a certain amount of space between orders?

Comment: Yes.  See for example https://www.researchgate.net/publication/249650727_Description_of_Diffraction_Grating_Behavior_in_Direction_Cosine_Space.